# Ajax request returns (406 Not Acceptable )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails app javascript template **profile.js.erb** don't get rendered. I get error code `406 Not Acceptable`.  This template is supposed to append a partial in a view **star#profile**. Ajax request is made by jquery infinite scroll plugin. Here is my code

.

**action**

```
 def profile
 @page=params[:page] ||1
 @videos=Video.all(:page=>@page)
 respond_to do |format|
 format.js
 format.html
  end
end
```

**view Stars#profile**

```
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
<%=render 'videos'%>
</div>
```

**profile.js.erb**

```
  $('div.post').append("<%=escape_javascript(render 'videos')%>");
```

**routes**

```
      match "stars/profile/:page"=> "stars#profile", :via => :get
```

**log in console**

```
Started GET "/stars/profile?page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 00:05:58 -0500
Processing by StarsController#profile as application/JavaScript
Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 65836ms
```

**Ajax setup**

```
   jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr, settings) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/javascript");
   var token=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',token );
   settings['dataType'] = "javascript";
   settings['contentType'] = "application/javascript";
    }
```

});

Comment: the comment next to Processing by StarController says profile as JSON. look to see what format is within your controller to ensure it's either html or js. If the format is json, that'll explain why you're getting the 406 since your controller isn't handling that format.

Comment: When i add format.json that solves the `406 error code` but i need ***profile.js.erb*** to get rendered not json

Comment: I think you have to set accept header in your request to `application/javascript`, not sure how to do it though, check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: I updated the question see my ajax set up.

Comment: the profile in the console log now says javascript. Is format not matching js still? It might also be useful to see the piece of code actually generating the request.

Answer (score 0):

From the log:
GET "/stars/profile?page=2" does not include .js after profile. So rails does not handle it at javascript.

GET "/stars/profile.js?page=2" should be the call..